# how to send last id of table and send to blade file in larvel 5.7?

Tags: laravel-5.7

I am fetching last_id from table now i want to send from controller to view. I got the following error

"htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\playout\resources\views\category.blade.php)
"

Controller:

```
 public function categoryLastId()
    {
         $category_type_id = DB::table('table_category_type')->orderBy('category_type_id','DESC')->first();
         return view('category',compact('category_type_id'));
    }
```

Blade:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
                                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Category id</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Category Id" name="id" readonly value="{{ $category_type_id}}">
                                                    </div>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: If your sql query is right then in blade `$category_type_id->id` try this

Comment: Why don't you dd() right before return statement check if you're getting right record from database or not ?